# In normal usage, is equality simply a context-dependent equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation, equivalence-relations

**In general, I am wondering that if we have some $x\equiv y \implies f(x) = f(y)$, can we promote $x \equiv y$ to $x=y$, as long as we "promise" to only discuss functions that respect this property?**

This seems to be the case for the construction of the integers as equivalence classes in $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. We define an equivalence relation first, and with the knowledge that, even though two elements from, say,  $1 = [(1,0)]$ (such as $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$, for instance) are unequal ordered pairs, they are equal in the sense that the arithmetic operations that we build on these notions will not discriminate between equivalent elements.

Then it seems like *equality is a sort of context-dependent equivalence relation*, and the choice to write $x = y$ rather than $x\equiv y$ may simply just be a matter of taste, in some cases. It may be the case that my understanding of equality is correct, in which case I would still be grateful for additional insight.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your example. I guess you refers to the construction of $\mathbb{Z}$ as the partition set generated by the following equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$: $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ iff $a + d = c + b$. According to such a construction, $[(1,0)]$ and $[(2,0)]$ are two distinct equivalence classes, representing the integers $1$ and $2$, respectively. So, I don't understand when you say that $[(1,0)]$ and $[(2,0)]$ "are equal in the sense that the arithmetic operations...".

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, I made a mistake there. To clarify, I mean that (1,0) + (2,0) = (2, 1) + (2, 0) = (3, 2) + (3, 1) = ... for example. Equivalent elements like (1, 0) and (2, 1) do not change the value after the function of addition to any element from [(2, 0)] is applied.

Comment: After your edit, I understand your question. Thank you.

Comment: As a contrast to the answers, while you *can* do this and this might even better reflect how mathematicians work in practice, this is *not* what is "actually" happening from a perspective of (typical) set theoretic foundations. In that context, we have only a single, logical notion of equality that applies to everything. $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ are always distinct, but $[(1,0)]$ and $[(2.1)]$ are simply literally equal sets, i.e. $\{p\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\mid p\sim(1,0)\}=\{p\in\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\mid p\sim(2,1)\}$ as you can compute.

Comment: @DerekElkins - I see your point but I guess the question is not about set theoretic foundations (in the original version, the question was not labeled by `set-theory`). Moreover, adopting a rigorous set-theoretic perspective, we cannot even say that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, which seems to be taken for granted by the OP.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco The nominal foundations that most mathematicians take is set theoretic, and the way equivalence classes work I described is the "standard" way. I would interpret the OP as saying $1_\mathbb Z=[(1_\mathbb N,0_\mathbb N)]$, but, yeah, there's a lot of abuse of notation when using set theoretic foundations. I agree that the OP isn't asking about the set theoretic view which is why I only wrote a comment, but it seemed worth mentioning (if only for future visitors) that what the OP describes is *not* the "standard" view and what the "standard" story is.

Comment: @DerekElkins I think you cleared up a fundamental misunderstanding I had about this construction of the integers. I believed that integers were not only equivalence classes of ordered pairs, but also the ordered pairs themselves. If it were the case that ordered pairs were integers, then, yes, we would "promote" equivalence to equality to say $1_{\mathbb{Z} } = (1, 0) = (2, 1)$. However, that is not necessary, because, as in the example you gave, $1_{\mathbb{Z} } = [(1, 0)] = [(2, 1)]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*: Yes, you can. And this is what working mathematicians actually do, in the vast majority of cases, using a sensible abuse of notation to avoid pedantry.

*Long answer*: In the following, I'll be pedantic on purpose, to justify the fact that we can get rid of pedantry and, under appropriate conditions, lift the equivalence relation $\equiv$ to an equality $=$. 
To avoid too abstract generality, let's see a concrete example. 
Consider the [construction of $\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1695198/288417) as the partition set generated by the following equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$: $(a,b) \equiv (c,d)$ if and only if $a+_\mathbb{N} d = c +_\mathbb{N} b$.

In such a context, we can define a function $+_\mathbb{Z}' \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ (acting on the elements of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$) such that 
\begin{align}
(a,b) +_\mathbb{Z}' (c,d) = (a +_\mathbb{N} c, b +_\mathbb{N} d).
\end{align}

It is immediate to prove that $+_\mathbb{Z}'$ is *compatible* with $\equiv$, i.e. it preserves equivalences classes: if $(a,b) \equiv (a',b')$ and $(c,d) \equiv (c',d')$ then $(a,b) +_\mathbb{Z}' (c,d) \equiv (a',b') +_\mathbb{Z}' (c',d')$ (indeed, $a + c + b' + d' = a' + c' + b + d$).
Therefore, it is natural to lift $+_\mathbb{Z}'$ to a function $+_\mathbb{Z} \colon \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (acting on the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$) defined by 
\begin{align}
[(a,b)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(c,d)] = [(a+_\mathbb{N} c,b+_\mathbb{N} d)].
\end{align}
Is this operation well-defined? Said differently, if we take different representatives  of the same equivalence class, do we get the same result (as an equivalence class)? The compatibility condition above gives us a positive answer, i.e. the definition of $+_\mathbb{Z}$ *does not depend* on the choice of the representative of the equivalence classes:  if $[(a,b)] = [(a',b')]$ and $[(c,d)] = [(c',d')]$ then $[(a,b)] +_\mathbb{Z} [(c,d)] = [(a',b')] +_\mathbb{Z} [(c',d')]$.
Thus, it is perfectly legitimate to collapse $+_\mathbb{Z}'$ and $+_\mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose now that you only work  on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$  with functions and relations defined on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ that respect the compatibility condition. In such a context, it is *impossible to distinguish*  $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$, and more in general  *two distinct representatives of the same equivalence class*. Therefore, in such a context, it is perfectly legitimate to collapse $\equiv$ (the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$) and $=$ (seen as the equality on $\mathbb{Z}$), in accordance with Leibniz's logical principle of [*identity of indiscernibles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles):  if two objects have the same properties, then they are identical.
The fact that $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$ are distinct ordered pairs does not matter as long as your are in a context where you cannot appreciate this difference, i.e. as long as you work only with functions and relations on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ that are compatible with the equivalence relation $\equiv$.

Answer (score 2):

Dully, given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$, you can just define its unique "equality" relation $=_\sim$ on $X$ to be $x=_\sim y\iff x\sim y$. If you interpret *every* notion of equality as arising in this sense, then yes equality is simply a context-dependent equivalence relation.

For example, let $X$ be a set of words in English and define $\sim$ on $X$ by $x\sim y$ iff they have the same length. Then the words 'game' and 'dome' are $\sim$-equal in the above sense but are not literally syntactically equal.

Answer (score 1):

After a little more study, I believe I am able to answer my own question. I stated that if we have an equivalence relation between objects and only discuss functions that respect the equivalence, then we can lift $a \equiv b$ to $a = b$. As Taroccoesbrocco mentioned, we can not discern a difference, so it is fine to do so.

However, we can do better by defining some equivalence classes to be the objects that our functions manipulate. Just let functions be defined for $[a] = [b]$. Now we have a true equality between equivalence classes, since $a \sim b$, and thus any function that we define on these objects can only truly be a function if it is well-defined for these equivalence class inputs.

For this reason, I believe it is not common to "upgrade" equivalence to equality when objects are indistinguishable with respect to some functions, as it is more desirable to use the above method. As Derek Elkins pointed out, this is what is done in the case of the construction of the integers, and I assume it is the usual proceure of resolving this problem of an imperfect context-dependent equality.

In short, $a \equiv b \implies [a] = [b] \implies f([a]) = f([b])$ is usually how we "promote" equivalence to equality, in which case equality is *not* context dependent.